# Notepad++ Regular Expression Replace Quotes Between Quoted Columns in CSV

Tags: regex, csv, notepad++

I have a comma separated CSV file with 3 quoted columns like this:

> "this","is good","data"

Some rows have extra quotes in the second column:

> "this","is "bad","data"
>
> "this","is "really" bad","data"

This site (http://editplus.info/wiki/Search_and_Replace_Tricks#Delete_everything_inside_a_tag_pair_.28keeping_tags.29) has a RegEx string to select the text between tags ("," in this case), but I only want to replace any quote characters between the tags, not the whole string. Ideally I would only select those lines which have the offending quotes.

RegEx that selects whole second column:

> (",").+(",")

RegEx that only selects the bad quotes or rows with them:

> ???

Any help is much appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

> Ideally I would only select those lines which have the offending quotes.

```
^.*(?:,|^)"[^,"\n]*"[^,\n"]*".*$
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/dL7jZ6/11)

To replace the mismatched quotes with empty string, use the below regex.

```
([^,\n])"([^,\n])
```

Then replace the matched characters with `\1\2`

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/dL7jZ6/14)

Comment: Thanks.If I were to replace the quotes with blank/null while keeping all other text, would the RegEx be the same? What would I put for Find and Replace With?

Comment: is your input contain only word characters? ie, is that your input contains charcaters other than alphabets or numbers or spaces or comma or double quotes?

Comment: Thanks again. Is there a way to handle replacing all quotes between the "," tags? If there are extra quotes like so: "this","is ""really" bad","data"    is it possible to replace all of them?

Answer (score 1):

**Try this:** It is tested **in notepad++** *for your all cases:*

search by `([^,\n\r\t])"+([^,\n\r\t])`  and replace with `$1$2`  (idea from @*Avinash Raj*)

**[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/dL7jZ6/16)**

**Update for next requirement which is include comment**

search by `(^"|","|"$)|"`  and replace with `$1`

[Update demo](https://regex101.com/r/dL7jZ6/17)

Comment: This almost works perfectly. Are there ways to handle edge cases where there may be quotes before commas within the middle column like this: **"This","Is Very", Bad","Data"**? The good quotes will always surround a comma on both sides.

Comment: Hi Ahosan, does the above comment make sense? Is it possible to replace quotes between "," tag pairs?

Comment: One last question with (^"|","|"$)|"   can you replace the quotes with a blank/null character?

Answer (score 0):

Running a match using: `/([\w ])"(?![,\n])/g`

And substituting with: `$1'`

Replaces all offending double quotes with single quotes, producing:

```
"this","is 'bad","data"
"this","is 'really' bad","data"
```

Demo here: https://regex101.com/r/dL7jZ6/12 (Credit to Avinash Raj for finding the demo website)

Comment: Thanks! This does select the quotes in the examples. What if wanted to select all quotes between the two "," tags.I put this in the demo:
"this",""is"really""" bad"","data"

Luckily, the first two columns will always have the same syntax.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the format is exactly how always how posted, I'd do something like:

[ ]".*?"